# SQL - remove all letters (alpha characters) from a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace, alphanumeric

I'm trying to write a function that removes any occurrence of any of the 26 alphabet letters from a string.

In: 'AA123A' -> Out: '123'

In: 'AB-123-CD% -> Out: '-123-%'

All I can find on Google is how to remove non-numeric characters, which all seem to be formed around defining the numbers you want to keep. But I want to keep any symbols too.

The 'simple' answer is 26 nested REPLACE for each letter, but I can't believe there isn't a better way to do it.
I could define a string of A-Z and loop through each character, calling the REPLACE 26 times - makes the code simpler but is the same functionally.

Does anyone have an elegant solution?

Comment: The elegant solution would be to do it using a programming language instead of in sql. Having said that, some databases support (or at least partially support) regular expressions - including regex_replace - which means it can be done with a single replace.

Comment: Different database platforms have different functions/syntax for this sort of thing. For example in postgres you can use regex, whereas with MS SQL Server this isn't always an option. It's a good idea (at the very least) to always add the tag for your particular platform/DBMS.

Comment: Thanks. It is an MS SQL server, specifically Azure SQL server. I'm pretty sure that regex_replace isn't supported as I have tried one of those. And unfortunately there isn't a lot we can do about the import of data.

Looks like it might be the loop - I've written one before for removing a parameterised string of symbols - so it's no big deal. It's just not really ideal as a method.

Comment: @lptr - Perfect also. I like the Replicate, making the code look a little less silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use TRANSLATE, e.g.:

```
SELECT REPLACE(TRANSLATE('AB-123-  CDdcba%', 'ABCDabcd','        '), ' ', '');
SELECT REPLACE(TRANSLATE('AB-123-  CDdcba%', 'ABCDabcd','AAAAAAAA'), 'A', '');
```

- first case trimming also spaces,
- second one, preserving existing spaces.

Just add the rest of characters to `'ABCDabcd'` argument and keep `'AAAAAAAA'` same length as the second argument.

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I needed. Thank you.